# How small is the smallest known carbon ring containing only double bonds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbon-allotropes

How small is the smallest known carbon ring containing only double bonds?

The stress from the double bonds makes small rings impossible to make something like cyclohexahexaene so I want to know how large the ring would need to be so the stress is small enough such that the ring can be made.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Isolated derivatives of *cyclo*-$\ce{C18}$ most likely have the smallest isolated cumulenic 18-membered ring, though upon direct complexation of transition metal in/outside the ring the strain as well as its size can be reduced further.

---

In the past two decades a research group of [Prof. Dr. François Diederich](http://www.diederich.chem.ethz.ch/) performed numerous studies on cyclo[*n*]carbons and monocyclic $\mathrm{sp}$-hybridized C-rings. He also published several reviews, e.g. see chapters "Cyclic and Linear Acetylenic Molecular Scaffolding" in [1, p. 43], and more recent "Oligoacetylenes" in [2, p. 443] devoted to versatile chemistry of [cumulenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulene).

As @R.M. referred in the comment, early theoretical work [3] predicted special Hückel-aromatic *cyclo*-$\ce{C18}$ compound stabilized *via* two orthogonal $(4n + 2)$ $\pi$-electron systems, but later computational studies predict somewhat controversial electronic structures (from [2]):

> Self-consistent field (SCF) calculations with a `3-21G` or larger basis set predicted that the cyclic *acetylenic* $D_{\mathrm{9h}}$ structure **1a** with alternating bond lengths represents the ground-state geometry[4].
>
> But optimizations at the Møller-Plesset second-order perturbation theory (MP2) level including valence electron correlations as well as density functional theory calculations favor the *cumulenic* $D_{\mathrm{18h}}$ structure **1b** as the most stable planar monocyclic geometry [5].
>
> [image]

More from [1, p. 46]:

> Accordingly, cyclo-$\ce{C10}$ is predicted to prefer a cumulenic $D_{\mathrm{5h}}$ structure, cyclo-$\ce{C14}$ is borderline, and the energies of its cumulenic $D_{\mathrm{7h}}$ and polyynic $C_{\mathrm{7h}}$ structures are nearly degenerate. It is clear that this fascinating theoretical controversy over the past years can only be definitively solved with the synthesis and characterization of cyclo-$\ce{C18}$.

cyclo-$\ce{C18}$ appeared to be a very elusive compound to isolate (on macroscoping scale typical products are anthracene and polymers), therefore only its derivatives were synthesized and characterized. Synthetic methods include the following paths: Retro-Diels-Alder; 3-Cyclobutene-l,2-dione route;  transition metal complexation [2]:

> [image]

Generally, cyclic cumulenes have two types of strains: distortion from linearity imposed by $\mathrm{sp}$-hybridization and distortion from orthogonality of adjacent double bonds (cyclo[*2n*]carbons). [6]

Attempts to liberate the cyclocarbons strain in cyclic cumulenes is similarly relieved by complexing one of the double bonds **directly** to a transition metal. For example, like in this zirconocene-hexapentaene complex, where $\ce{C=C=C}$ angle is reduced to approx. $130^\circ$ by complexation with $\ce{Zr}$ [7]:

[image]

Unfortunally, up to date there are only mononuclear metal-cumulene complexes isolated in a large scale, and none of them are cyclo[*n*]carbons, but theoretically polynuclear transition metal complexation can significantly reduce the ring size.

#### References

1. Carbon Rich Compounds II, Macrocyclic Oligoacetylenes and Other Linearly Conjugated Systems; de Meijere, A., Ed.; Topics in Current Chemistry; Springer Berlin Heidelberg: Berlin, Heidelberg, **1999**; Vol. 201; ISBN 3540653015.
2. Stang, P. J.; Diederich, F. Modern Acetylene Chemistry; Wiley-VCH: Weinheim, **2008**; ISBN 9783527615261.
3. Hoffmann, R. *Tetrahedron* **1966**, 22 (2), 521–538. DOI [10.1016/0040-4020(66)80020-0](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-4020(66)80020-0).
4. Diederich, F.; Rubin, Y.; Knobler, C. B.; Whetten, R. L.; Schriver, K. E.; Houk, K. N.; Li, Y. *Science* **1989**, 245 (4922), 1088–1090. DOI [10.1126/science.245.4922.1088](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.245.4922.1088).
5. Hutter, J.; Luethi, H. P.; Diederich, F. *J. Am. Chem. Soc*. **1994**, 116 (2), 750–756. DOI [10.1021/ja00081a041](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00081a041).
6. Stone, F. G. A.; West, R. Advances in organometallic chemistry; **1998**; Vol. 42. ISBN 0120311429.
7. Suzuki, N.; Hashizume, D.; Yoshida, H.; Tezuka, M.; Ida, K.; Nagashima, S.; Chihara, T. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2009**, 131 (6), 2050–2051. DOI [10.1021/ja8077472](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja8077472).

Comment: If you have the time, would you consider updating this since $\ce{C18}$ itself has been made? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclo(18)carbon https://science.sciencemag.org/content/365/6459/1299 Or I could do it one of these days, if you prefer.