# Do molecules containing only carbon exist?

Tags: molecules, carbon-allotropes

Why doesn't carbon form bonds with itself to form a molecule? Carbon shows the property of catenation, so why doesn't it form a cyclic molecule such as:

```
 C = C 
 ‖   ‖ 
 C = C
```

Comment: graphene, diamond, fullerenes ...

Comment: also relevant : https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43887/how-small-is-the-smallest-known-carbon-ring-containing-only-double-bonds

Comment: buckyball also...

Comment: Diamond and graphene if not engineered down do not qualify as molecules. Buckyballs is a nik for Buckminsterfullerenes. See Oscar Lanzi below for an answer

Comment: That *specific* molecule would be monstrously unstable due to ring strain. But plenty of other molecules with just carbon would not be and many exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They do form.  Besides [fullerenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene), there are carbon molecules with varying numbers of atoms [around some stars[1]](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1987ApJ...314..352K). Vaporized graphite in such envirinments produce chains of 3 to 30 carbobs and larger spheroidal clusters of 40 to as many as 100 carbins. These may combine with hydrogen and nitrogen to form circumstellar polyynes. Such molecular forms are, of course, less stable than the macromolecular structures we more commonly see under ambient conditions.

**Reference**

1. H. W. Kroto, J. R. Heatth, S. C. O'Brien, R. F. Curl. R. E. Smalley (1987). "Long Carbon Chain Molecules in Circumstellar Shells". *The Astrophysical Journal* **314**, 352-355.