# Is cyclo[18]carbon aromatic?

Tags: resonance, carbon-allotropes, aromaticity

How does [this](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2019/08/16/a-new-form-of-carbon) compound even exist? Having such a massive ring strain.

Is it even conjugated? As it's resonance structure will have all double bonds.

Since it was reported to be found, there must be some stabilizing factor. I was wondering whether that might be aromaticity, since it does have 4n+2 electrons.

Comment: Usually, when you're reading on bleeding edge chemistry, it's safer to assume the compounds are not stable at all. If you read the article more closely, you'd see that it speaks of interstellar space and very low temperatures, and only a few of the molecule were ever spotted.

Comment: The compound doesn't quite exist. Then again, the ring strain isn't all that massive (think cyclopropane).

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119283/why-does-the-image-of-cyclo18carbon-look-like-a-nonagon